# How to handl these routes in go httprouter: /hello/:name and /hello/b/c?

Tags: http, go, httprouter

httprouter does not allow this and panics when start.

> httprouter :panic: wildcard route ':name' conflicts with existing
> children in path  '/hello/:name'.

In my understanding,
"/hello/:name" has two parts ,but /hello/b/c has three parts.
"/hello/:name" will match any url has two parts which prefix /hello
"/hello/b/c" only match /hello/b/c

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Welcome!\n")
}

func Index2(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Welcome222!\n")
}

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/hello/b/c", Index2)

    router.GET("/hello/:name", Index)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

Comment: `:name` in the second path conflicts with `b` in the first path. It doesn't matter how many segments the paths have, what matters is that their prefix is the same. And, as the error suggests, this is not allowed by `httprouter`. The solution is either A. to not use such paths, or B. to not use `httprouter` and instead use one that supports such paths.

Comment: if you want to match variable length paths of a single method, GET, with the same prefix - httprouter suggests the `*` syntax over `:`. So instead of `/hello/:name` you write `/hello/*name` which will now handle both `/hello/john` and `/hello/b/c` and anything else after `hello/` with the name param. Of course you may choose to use some library else entirely as @mkopriva suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the line `router.GET("/hello/b/c", Index2)` and then have:

```
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    if strings.HasPrefix(ps.ByName("name"), "b/c") {
        return Index2(w, r, ps)
    } else {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Welcome!\n")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very inconvenient, as I have found, too. There isn't a great solution.

Two things can be found:

1. Make a fork of httprouter and modify tree.go (on first glance, this seems to be it).
2. Use the "catch-all" wildcard `*name` and handle the route in your own function with an early return.

Which is preferable depends on how many of this type of routes exist, but 2 is probably better.